# mapstruct 1.3.1FINAL: @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") doesn't support custom bean name references mapstruct/mapstruct#1427

Tags: java, mapstruct

My problem references to this issue here on github https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1427

I got at least two versions of mappers with the same name. I want to use springs getBean/Autowired possibilities but this doesn't work out of the mapstructs box yet. :-)

I followed the second workaround mentioned in the upper link: extend Springs bean naming strategy. Did someone ever get this well ment proposal working?

If i follow the code parts from there the bean naming doesn't take place. For me its's clear why not: there aren't any components to scan and especially to find.

If i add a componenModel = "spring" to the mapper annotation i get a ConflictingBeanDefinitionException. Don't know why. Maybe there's a cat in the tail problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated from Filip here https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1427 i followed his approach and with a few modifications it worked. I added a solution comment in the link.

The main changes are:

1. i added `componentModel = "spring"` to my mappers and used a filter to exclude all of my mapper classes (the interface all of my mappers are implementing: MapperInterface.class) within the Spring Boot application.
2. To my Spring Boot application class i added:

   `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.application.spring_boot_class" }, excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { MapperInterface.class }, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE) })`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, and I resolved it using the `Spring bean` definition in a configuration class, a class annotated with `@Configuration`, with the `Mapstruct` mapper call like below:

```
@Bean
public IMyMapper offerWebMapper() {
    return Mappers.getMapper(IMyMapper.class);
}
```

And then you can inject the mapper using `@Autowired` or `getBean`.

Comment: Thx Ismail, another nice way. Hope that Filip (from mapstruct) gives his opinion here :-)

Comment: ...and i want to say, that i really like mapstruct. hopefully there will be a way in the future to get that working. I would say this use case is a very tipically one...

Comment: Yes, it's very typical, I've tried to use another way, but I found that very useful and simple.

Comment: I would strongly advise against doing something like this. Especially if you are using dependencies between mappers. When you don't use the spring component model then MapStruct will use `Mapper.getMapper` to get the mappers that it needs to reuse.